# changing class of element in django template using javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, django, date

In my django template I have some Event items listed using a for loop.The event has an associated date_of_occurrence attribute which is a python DateTime.I need to make the background for the event red ,if the datetime is less than current datetime.

I thought of doing it like this

In template

```
<ul>
{% for  event in events %}
  <div id="event_div"
    <li>
       event.name<br>
       event.date_of_occurrence
    </li>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In css

```
.pastevent{
  background-color:red;
}
```

I need a javascript function to set the class of element with id  `event_div`  to `pastevent`.Can someone tell me how this function can be implemented?

As I understand the function is not fired by any click event ,but when page loads. How will the datetime value of event passed  from the template  to do the comparison  to the current javascript date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't necessarily have to use javascript to do this. There are a couple of different options using the template tags.

The simpler approach (and more crude) would be to render the current datetime to the template as eg. current_date then do a logic check in your template.

```
{% for  event in events %}
    {% if event.date_of_occurrence < current_date %}  
    <div id="pastevent">
    {% else %}
    <div id="event_div">
    {% endif %}
    <li>
       event.name<br>
       event.date_of_occurrence
    </li>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The other option would be to create a custom template filter that returns whether the event was in the past or not and apply the same logic as above.

Comment: that is a good suggestion..but when I compare `{% event.date_of_occurrence < now %}` it always returns false

Comment: Is that now as in the template tag? in either case now is a template tag so you will have to use a different name for the current date value in the render dict. If you are trying to use the date as now the template tag it likely won't work as that is used for rendering a string of the current date,  but I will check something and get back to you.

Comment: Yup. I just tested the logic in my answer above and it works if you render the current_date in your view. ie. {'current_date': date.today()} along with your other data in the view. With that the above template logic works. If it still doesn't work for you I can post some code.

Comment: thanks  @jondykeman , I passed the datetime value from view and now it works.. The template tag `now` will not work ..didn't think about that before